# PHP Respect Validation password confirmation

Tags: php, validation, slim, respect-validation

I used slim 3 framework with `davidepastore/slim-validation` to validate my data.

`davidepastore/slim-validation` itself uses `Respect validation` rules.

I used validation in middleware (in router file):

```
use DavidePastore\Slim\Validation\Validation;
use app\Controllers\RegisterController;
.
.
.

$app->post("register" ,[RegisterController::class , "register"])->add(new Validation(RegisterController::RegisterValidate(),$translator));
```

RegisterController::RegisterValidate() return some rules like :

```
[
      "password"              => v::length(6, 18) ,
      "password_confirmation" => v::key('password_confirmation', v::equals(v::key('password'))),
]
```

But it did not work.
Always return error.
Error message is  "Key {{name}} must be present".

I used the  `v::keyValue('password_confirmation', 'equals', 'password')` but it made no difference and returned the same error.
Am I using the wrong method?
Is it possible to reach the desired answer from this method?
Or I have to change my method.

My request (JSON):

```
{
    "username":"example@test.com",
    .
    .
    .
    "password":"123654s",
    "password_confirmation":"123654s",
    .
    .
    .
    "name" : "Milito"
}
```

And I used `POST` HTTP method

Comment: Hi! Could you please also share your request and the used HTTP method?

Comment: Sure! I added to my question. @DavidePastore